# Parsing through free text field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a field in my table that has different types of data in it which can be translated into different columns or rows.

| Free Text Field | TypeID |
| --- | --- |
| {Visit Info}[<Visit Date>2022-01-01</Visit Date><Visit Type>Clinical</Visit Type>]{/Visit Info}{Costs}[<Laboratory>30.91</Laboratory><Encounter>15.00</Encounter>]{/Costs} | 1 |
| {Index Events}[<Date>2022-03-04</Date><Diagnosis>I10</Diagnosis>]{/Index Events} | 2 |
| {Visit Info}[<Visit Date>2022-10-12</Visit Date><Visit Type>Administrative</Visit Type>]{/Visit Info}{Costs}[<Consultation>25.00</Consultation>]{/Costs} | 1 |

The idea is that the data is enclosed in {Category}, <Subcategory> and then the data related to the <Subcategory>. I need to write a query that returns the data like in the following result set:

| TypeID | Category | Subcategory | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Visit Info | Visit Date | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | Visit Info | Visit Type | Clinical |
| 1 | Costs | Laboratory | 30.91 |
| 1 | Costs | Encounter | 15.00 |
| 2 | Index Events | Date | 2022-03-04 |
| 2 | Index Events | Diagnosis | I10 |
| 1 | Visit Info | Visit Date | 2022-10-12 |
| 1 | Visit Info | Visit Type | Administrative |
| 1 | Costs | Consultation | 25.00 |

I'd appreciate it if I could be pointed to the right direction in terms of what functions to use.

I'm using SSMS on SQL Server 2016

---

For anyone wondering, I ended up replacing the "{" and "}" values with "<" and ">" respectively and removing the "[" and "]" values.

After this I cast the field as XML and used XML nodes to parse through the field, like so:

```
SELECT
TypeID,
UniqueID,
[Free Text Field],
tbl.col.value('local-name(..)','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,
tbl.col.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,
tbl.col.value('.[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Value
FROM [My Table] a
CROSS APPLY [My Table].[Free Text Field].nodes('/*/*') AS tbl(col)
```

Comment: SQL is the wrong place to parse free-form text.

Comment: I would 100% pull this out into a language that can deal with this strange XML tokenized whatever-this-is text. SQL, especially sql server of all RDBMS platforms, lacks the functionality to slice and dice this. Python would be my tool of choice. Pull it out, parse it into relational data, and blow it back into the database.

Comment: You might be able to do this with the XML parser if you pull out the XML part (why isn't the whole thing XML?)   You should also note there is a problem with your output -- how do you know lines 1-4 are related and lines 7-9 are related -- I think you need one more column in the output.

Comment: I'm stuck using SQL in this case.

Comment: As for lines 1-4 and 7-9 being related, in my real data, there is another field that's unique, I would use that one instead.

Comment: pull the data using sql alchemy into python then parse the xml into a dictionary then insert the record back into a sql database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data looked like this then it would be valid XML and would be easy to parse with the XML parser

| Free Text Field | TypeID |
| --- | --- |
| `<Visit Info><Visit Date>2022-01-01</Visit Date><Visit Type>Clinical</Visit Type></Visit Info><Costs><Laboratory>30.91</Laboratory><Encounter>15.00</Encounter></Costs>` | 1 |
| `<Index Events><Date>2022-03-04</Date><Diagnosis>I10</Diagnosis></Index Events>` | 2 |
| `<Visit Info><Visit Date>2022-10-12</Visit Date><Visit Type>Administrative</Visit Type></Visit Info><Costs><Consultation>25.00</Consultation></Costs>` | 1 |

Comment: I could just make a REPLACE(REPLACE(FreeTextField,'{','<'),'}','>') statement inside my query and parse through it that way, right?

Comment: @raltandi -- no you have [ ] too

Comment: If I replace those as well, I'd need to use OPENXML?

Comment: or FOR XML -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: also note -- replace is very slow -- if you can convert once and store in the table (in XML data type column) you will see significant performance improvements

Comment: Thank you, I will use FOR XML and store the replaced results in a staging table. Appreciate the time you took to point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot with substring, like:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECt 'Visit Info' as category, 'Visit Date' as subcategory  UNION
   SELECt 'Costs' as category, 'Laboratory' as subcategory 
  )
SELECT 
   typeid,
   category,
   subcategory,
   SUBSTRING(ss,y1+len(subcategory)+2,y2-(y1+len(subcategory)+2)) as value
FROM (  
   SELECT 
      typeid,
      category,
      subcategory,
      SUBSTRING(free,x1+len(category)+2,x2-(x1+len(category)+2)) as ss,
      CHARINDEX(CONCAT('<',subcategory,'>'),SUBSTRING(free,x1+(len(category)+2),x2-x1+len(category)+2+1)) as y1,
      CHARINDEX(CONCAT('</',subcategory,'>'),SUBSTRING(free,x1+(len(category)+2),x2-x1+len(category)+2+1)) as y2
   FROM (
      SELECT 
         typeid,
         category,
         free,
         subcategory,
         CHARINDEX(CONCAT('{',category,'}'),free) as x1,
         CHARINDEX(CONCAT('{/',category,'}'),free) as x2
      FROM test
      CROSS APPLY cte )x
   WHERE x1<>0 and x2>x1
) y
WHERE y1<>0 and y2>y1 ;
```

The other category and subcategory's can be done in the same way

Output of this:

| typeid | category | subcategory | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Costs | Laboratory | 30.91 |
| 1 | Visit Info | Visit Date | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | Visit Info | Visit Date | 2022-10-12 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/WAo3TROF)